# Issue with Bio.Entrez and protein in Biopython 1.60

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi, protein-database

I'm having a issue using Bio.Entrez to search a protein. I'm doing this:

```
>>> handle=Entrez.esearch(db="protein", term="insulin AND homo")
>>> record=Entrez.read(handle)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 351, in read
    record = handler.read(handle)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 169, in read
    self.parser.ParseFile(handle)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 307, in endElementHandler
    raise RuntimeError(value)
RuntimeError: Search Backend failed: Database is not supported: protein
```

I'm having a issue with einfo() too, check at this:

```
>>> handler=Entrez.einfo(db="protein")
>>> record=Entrez.read(handler)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 351, in read
    record = handler.read(handle)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 169, in read
    self.parser.ParseFile(handle)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 285, in startElementHandler
    raise ValidationError(name)
Bio.Entrez.Parser.ValidationError: Failed to find tag 'Build' in the DTD. To skip all tags that are not represented in the DTD, please call Bio.Entrez.read or Bio.Entrez.parse with validate=False.
```

Why is protein database not supported? Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the first issue with BioPython 1.60. (Are you certain that opening your Python terminal and pasting in `from Bio import Entrez; Entrez.email = "dgrtwo@princeton.edu"; handle=Entrez.esearch(db="protein", term="insulin AND homo"); record=Entrez.read(handle); print record` causes that error?)

Comment: >>> print Bio.__version__
1.60
Entrez.email = "dgrtwo@princeton.edu"; handle=Entrez.esearch(db="protein", term="insulin AND homo"); record=Entrez.read(handle); print record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 351, in read
    record = handler.read(handle)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py", line 169, in read
....
RuntimeError: Search Backend failed: Database is not supported: protein


Yes, still the same error. Did you compile Biopython or install from repositories?

Comment: OK, this is strange. Running the same code a couple of times caused it to sometimes cause the error and sometimes not. Can you try running that first code again?

Comment: I installed using `pip install biopython` (freshly right now)

Comment: I used "aptitude install python-biopython" but is always generating the same error, maybe I should compile ...

Comment: I downloaded, compiled and installed from the official web, and running the same code a couple of times caused it to sometimes cause the error and sometimes not. That's really strange.

Comment: you could also ask http://www.biostars.org

Answer (score 1):

Also raised on the Biopython mailing list, and apparently working now:
http://lists.open-bio.org/pipermail/biopython/2013-January/008306.html

We think this was a transient problem at the NCBI.